# AnimationDrawable vs game loop

Tags: android

In my app, there is one screen that has a lot of animation. Basically a map (sort of like any strategy game) with buildings that are showing looping animation (for example smoke coming out). All of them are static in their places but just their looks are animated.

I am using animationdrawable for all of them ( being the easiest way to loop through frames at certain time intervals).

My question is, should I stop this and go into using Game loop? And why?

Thanks